# Can every De Rham cohomology class be represented by a closed form $\alpha$ with $L_X \alpha=0$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, derham-cohomology, differential-forms

Assume  that  $M$  is  a  manifold  and  $X$ is  a  vector field on $M$.

Is it true to say that every closed form is De Rham-cohomologue to  a  closed form $\alpha$  with $L_X \alpha =0$?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko  For open orientable manifolds the question has obviously positive answer in their last  cohomology. So I am curious if the  question has trivial answer in all  cases, compact or  non compact, in all  cohomology dimension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the vector field $X=x\partial_x$ on the real projective line, so with affine coordinate $x$. Then in another affine chart $y=1/x$, $X=-y\partial_y$, so $X$ is smooth everywhere. Every 1-form on the real projective line is closed. An invariant 1-form has to be $\alpha=C dx/x$. To be defined near $x=0$, it has to be $0$. But on the real projective line, there is cohomology in dimension 1, as the real projective line is the circle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer  and your  attention to my question. Is there a  compact manifold which satisfy the property mentioned in the question?

Comment: or is  there a  non compact  manifold with this property  whose total cohomology is  not vanished?

Comment: If a compact Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a manifold $M$, then every smooth closed form on $M$ is cohomologous to a $G$ invariant closed form, by averaging over the biinvariant volume form on $G$. So there are interesting examples, like the circle with a rotation vector field.